# TYPO3 9.5: No class named TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\ExtensionManagerConfigurationUtility

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I have the following problem accessing the "Settings > Extension Configuration" menu in my backend.

```
No class named TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\ExtensionManagerConfigurationUtility
Ajax Error

#1294585866 InvalidArgumentException
No class named TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\ExtensionManagerConfigurationUtility

in /data/www/www.my-domain.de/public/typo3_src-9.5.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 3607
```

TYPO3 suggests to "check for broken Extensions" - no problems found.

I already tried to access the menu with all extensions disabled - same problem.

We upgraded our page a little while ago but since I did not find a fix for this issue. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The class namespace has been changed as the extension *saltedpasswords* has been merged into the core. See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Deprecation-85833-ExtensionSaltedpasswordsMergedIntoCoreExtension.html?highlight=extensionmanagerconfigurationutility for the documentation.

As a solution, use `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\ExtensionManagerConfigurationUtility`

Comment: I saw that on the documentation but I was not able to find where the old namespace was used.

Comment: @George, default settings not being reflected. Even in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['my_ext']` or `unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['download_explorer'])`. Let's say, if extension installed first time.